# Link to a Document by UNC

Tags: document-library, content-type, hyperlink, content

I've seen some old discussions about this but nothing current, so thought I'd throw it out there:

Using MOSS/WSS 3.0, I'm looking for ways (without Visual Studio) to allow a new Link to a Document to be created without forcing validation of the http: or https: prefix. Know that I can create using a dummy URL and then edit afterward but that's not acceptable in this instance.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific at what you want to do?

Comment: I have a document library in a Project Web Access (WSS3.0) workspace and some users have files larger than I want to allow in the content database. In order to have the links to those files commingled with docs in the library I'm using the "Link to a Document" content type. There's a validation function baked into newlink.aspx that forces the URL to contain the http or https prefix. We can work around that by changing to file: on editform.aspx because the validation isn't present there but users reject that solution.

Comment: So the goal is to allow a user to go to New - Link to Document and select a document to link to? What is the expected outcome? Sorry, still missing the sequence you want to happen!

Comment: So the current user experience when using Link to a Document is simply a prompt for a URL and a description, where the user simply pastes or enters a URL. That URL must begin with http or https due to validation baked into the newlink.aspx form. My use case is that the target isn't a URL but rather a UNC path for a network storage location, e.g. \myshare\folder\file.doc. UNC paths are addressable using the file:// prefix but newlink.aspx won't accept that as a valid URL.

Comment: Is jQuery an option here or not?

Comment: jQuery, absolutely. I use it elsewhere but usually just by adapting other solutions as my scripting skills are weak.

Answer (score 1):

Eric,

I saw this post out on Technet earlier that may be what you're looking for. Admittedly, I haven't tried it, but it looked like it might work.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/3f2c34cc-5686-4e03-ba26-092aaa29ff33

I see you're looking for a non-VS route, I've done something similar with a DVWP before, using the XSLT to write a UNC path instead of an http path, but it's not a very "reusable" solution. I suppose if you're just looking for a view or two it may work for you though.

Comment: Yeah, saw that post myself and discarded it because a no-code solution is required here and the solution would need to be a little more reusable than converting to a DVWP. Thanks for the thought!

Answer (score 1):

To add a UNC path to a Links list, use file:// in front of it and change the backslashes to forward slashes.  For example: \share\folder\file.doc would be file://share/folder/file.doc

Comment: John, this isn't a links list unfortunately. Have to commingle the links in question with docs in a library so I'm using the "Link to a Document" content type.

Answer (score 0):

in SharePoint exist a special content type called "link to document" after you added this to your list or library you can store file links to http and unc too.

How to enable link to document you should check out the following link.
http://vspug.com/mindykelly/2007/09/11/add-a-link-to-a-document-within-a-document-library-in-moss/

I'm not sure if you can add unc directly or if you need to add the url representance of a file link.
You should check out the uri schema for file on the wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Path formated like this can also be added to normal link lists too as John Chapman allready recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm answering your question here, albeit for SharePont 2010.  We resolved the issue for the Links list.  To use a file:// location rather than an http:// location, you'll need to use JQuery. Follow the instructions here:

http://www.sharepointindepth.com/change-hyperlink-field-value-from-http-to-file-on-a-sharepoint-form/

Comment: You should not post link only answers, please try to add more details to your answer to make it less dependent on the link (that might break)

Answer (score -1):

Check this, this the best adequate solution Ifound & used : 
http://lindachapman.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-add-link-to-document-external-to.html